# How do I fill in the holes in wooden window frames?

Tags: windows, woodworking, drill

I drilled a few holes to window frames in my rented house hoping to setup a steel mosquito mesh with screws rather than small nails to be removed easily in the future.

I hurriedly used a 3 mm drill bit. The holes are easily visible and I want to fill them now. They are just 6 holes not deeper than 1 centimeter.

**More details:**

- Number of windows: 2
- Number of holes: 6 per window frame
- Diameter of the holes: 3mm
- Depth: 1cm to 2 cm

Could anybody tell me the best way to fill them? I am thinking of applying putty and paint with the same colors but I don't know if that covers the holes completely.

Answer (score 1):

If the window frames are made of wood, I would use wood filler to fill the holes.

You won't be able to conceal the holes from a forensic crime-scene examiner but that is not your goal. You need to restore the property to a state that will satisfy a reasonable owner that you have looked after it and kept it in good repair so that it can be rented out once you have terminated your lease.

It is always wise, before drilling holes in someone else's property, to ask the owner.

If in doubt, ask the owner what she would like you to do.

Comment: The owner already said we can make holes whereever necessary and fill them when we move. But I think smaller holes are enough and I am taking precautions to avoid any issues with those few holes that I made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put a small amount of putty into the hole then break off a toothpick (or two if they both fit) into the hole. You'll want to then sand/file down the toothpick to match the surface of the hole and area around it for better contact with the new paint. Finish filling in the hole with putty if there is still room around the tooth pick and continue to sand until smooth, using a 150+ grit paper at the lowest.